# PHPExcell fetching special characters from database

Tags: special-characters, phpexcel, xls

I'm trying to create an xls file from php using PHPExcel and fetching data from a mysql database.
The sentece that gives me problem is something like "Corda Flessibile Antifiamma 1x16mm² NERO - € 1,21"
If I get it from DB the PHPExcel write "FALSE" to the file. Code like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$string = $array['value'];
$activeSheet->setCellValue("B1", $string); //output => "FALSE"
```

BUT if I type it in the source code I get no problems and it is written to the file. COde like:

```
$activeSheet->setCellValue("B1", "Corda Flessibile Antifiamma 1x16mm² NERO - € 1,21"); //output correct => "Corda Flessibile Antifiamma 1x16mm² NERO - € 1,21"
```

Does anyone has ever encountered this same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPExcel expects strings to be UTF-8.

If you're pulling a non-UTF-8 character set value from the database, convert it to UTF-8 before writing it to PHPExcel.

Comment: when I set up the connection to DB, I use:
mysql_query('set names utf8_general_ci');

Comment: Have you done "SET NAMES utf8" when your script connects to the database?

Comment: Yes. I don't know why it does not work.
Anyway, using mb_convert_encoding() I got it to work. thanks